# How to set attributes of has_many associations in callback within a ActiveRecord transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rooms
  before_save :update_lat_lng

  def update_lat_lng
    self.rooms.update_all(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude)
  end
end

class Rooms < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end
```

The location model has `before_save` callback, which updates the rooms that is associated to the location instance.

In doing this way, I update the rooms attributes **before** I actually save the location. This runs the risk of location not being written to database but the rooms being written to database.

I want to wrap the changes in a single ActiveRecord transaction. If each location `has_one` room only, it can be done with

```
def update_lat_lng
  self.room.latitude = self.latitude
  self.room.longitude = self.longitude
end
```

But for a has_many association, Im still scratching my head. I have trid the following to no avail.

```
def update_lat_lng
  self.rooms.each do |food|
    self.room.latitude = self.latitude
    self.room.longitude = self.longitude
  end
end
```

Comment: off topic: why would you want to save the lat/long data on the Room records when you already have it stored in the Location record? You could delegate the `latitude` and `longitude` to the `location` object. With this logic, you would not have to care about the `after_save` and `before_save` callbacks.

Comment: Ahh Im using thinking-sphinx geo-search on rooms entity, but it does not seem to work if the lat and long are ruby methods and not columns of the room entity..am trying out if it works if they are columns...but anyway I have come across this problem before

Comment: Oh okay then a regular `after_save :update_lat_lng` with your first implementation of `update_lat_lng` (the one with the `update_all`) should work fine.

Comment: it works fine but it runs the risk of saving the rooms first but not the location since both actions are no longer wrapped in a single ActiveRecord transaction, resulting in discrepancies...I understand the probability is low but i guess there has to be a better and correct way...unless im mistaken that update_all does not save to database in a callback hmmm

Comment: if you use the `after_save` callback then the rooms won't be saved before the location record. But if you use methods that don't run callbacks (like `Location.update_all(longitude: 0)` then the associated locations records won't be updated.

Comment: ahh is that so? cool Ill try it again someday. thanks!